# How to Sort an array in swift based on another array element attribute

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

So, i have these arrays:

```
let persons = [{idPerson: 4, name: "John"}, {idPerson: 2, name: "Bill"}, {idPerson: 3, name: "Vivian"}, {idPerson: 1, name: "Max"}]
let positions = [{idPerson: 1, value: 5}, {idPerson: 2, value:6}, {idPerson: 3, value: 7}, {idPerson: 4, value: 8}]
```

I want to sort the array *persons*, based on *positions* array, by the attribute *value*.

The *idPerson* is the attribute that connect both arrays.

How is the best way to do that ?

Comment: Why have two arrays of dictionaries? Why not have one array of `struct`?

Comment: The best way is to not have 2 arrays. Create an array of structs. Sort that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct PerosonRemote {
    var personID: Int
    var name: String
}

struct Position {
    var personID: Int
    var value: Int
}

struct Peroson {
    var value: Int
    var name: String
}

let personsRemote = [PerosonRemote(personID: 4, name: "John"),   
                     PerosonRemote(personID: 2, name: "Bill"), 
                     PerosonRemote(personID: 3, name: "Vivian"), 
                     PerosonRemote(personID: 1, name: "Max")]  

let positionsRemote = [Position(personID: 1, value: 5),
                       Position(personID: 2, value: 6),
                       Position(personID: 3, value: 7),
                       Position(personID: 4, value: 8)]

func getValue(forPersonID id: Int) -> Int {
    for position in positionsRemote {
        if position.personID == id {
            return position.value
        }
    }

    return 0 // Not found PersonID
}


var persons = [Peroson]()

personsRemote.forEach { (person) in
    persons.append(Peroson(value: getValue(forPersonID: person.personID), name:     person.name))
}

var sortedPersons = persons.sorted { $0.value > $1.value }

print(sortedPersons)
```